# Early 2008 Macbook Ubuntu LTS 16.04 stuck in tty1

Tags: macbook

I have an early 2008, macbook core 2 duo with 4GB of RAM and the Intel graphics card that comes standard with this model. It was wiped when I bought it. I made a Live DVD and managed to install Ubuntu using rEFInds newest version.

The problem I am having is that I cannot get to my desktop. I have tried a wired connection to the internet but the macbook will not connect to the internet and will not leave tty1. I have installed Ubuntu on another macbook before that was a similar model. But I have never had this happen. I am pretty new to programming.

How can I fix my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your desktop isn't hidden in another virtual console? I Have this problem sometimes on my Macbook Pro 4.1 (with Nvidia graphics), I get the desktop by switching to `TTY7` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>).

Anyway it seems this hardware doesn't really fit Ubuntu 16.04 64bit: I'm having problems with boot (long delay then an `ata3 srts error`), suspend and (never) resume...

Hope you'll get your Mac working!